# Need help in aligning consecutive assignment little differently

Tags: c++, clang-format

I use clang-format option AlignConsecutiveAssignments: true for C++. However, for the cases like the one below, I would like to avoid extra spacing.

Current output:

```
    int i                                 = 0;
    int vol                               = 0;
    int mass                              = 0;
    string center_of_mass                 = "";
    unsigned center_of_gravity            = 0;
    int j                                 = 0;
    int wt                                = 0;
    int longest_variable_name_of_them_all = 0;
    // int a           = 0;
    cout << "item1       = " << wt << endl;
    cout << "longer_item = " << vol << endl;
```

Desired piecewise alignment result:

```
    int i    = 0;
    int vol  = 0;
    int mass = 0;
    string center_of_mass = "";
    unsigned center_of_gravity = 0;
    int j  = 0;
    int wt = 0;
    int longest_variable_name_of_them_all = 0;
    // int a           = 0;
    cout << "item1       = " << wt << endl;
    cout << "longer_item = " << vol << endl;
```

As a rule of thumb I want to avoid having more than 4 spaces before = (and that's why center_of_mass misaligns with the next line).

Does anyone have a script I can run on the formatted output file? Comments are to be ignored to preserve ASCII art (if any) in them :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is desired is impossible in clang-format. You can achive it partially by disabling clang-format in code regions like below

```
int i    = 0;
int vol  = 0;
int mass = 0;
// clang-format off
string center_of_mass = "";
unsigned center_of_gravity = 0;
// clang-format on
int j  = 0;
int wt = 0;
// clang-format off
int longest_variable_name_of_them_all = 0;
// clang-format on
// int a           = 0;
cout << "item1       = " << wt << endl;
cout << "longer_item = " << vol << endl;
```

Or you can break declarations with empty lines and join long names in code blocks bounced by empty lines.

```
int i    = 0;
int vol  = 0;
int mass = 0;
int j    = 0;
int wt   = 0;

string center_of_mass      = "";
unsigned center_of_gravity = 0;

int longest_variable_name_of_them_all = 0;

// int a           = 0;
cout << "item1       = " << wt << endl;
cout << "longer_item = " << vol << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually in the real code variables were grouped by functionality and the original author did not approve permuting them. I will accept the answer, will handle it by some external script instead of disabling-enabling formatting.

Comment: Why not just use your keyboard to type the number of spaces you want?